# How to track user finger movement in Android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm currently working on an android app using canvas. I'm drawing specific shapes and I can detect the touch inside the shape.

I want to track or detect whether the user colored the whole shape or at least a pourcentage of it.

[this is an exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCtay.jpg)

Comment: Okay. Do you have [mcve]? If yes, please [edit] your question and post here.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement touch event listner for that.

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int X = (int) event.getX();
            int Y = (int) event.getY();
            int eventaction = event.getAction();

            switch (eventaction) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Finger down coordinate " + "X: " + X + " Y: " + Y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    isTouch = true;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Finger move coordinate " + "X: " + X + " Y: " + Y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Finger up coordinate " + "X: " + X + " Y: " + Y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I expressed my idea well. Imagine I draw for exemple a banana as a shape with canvas, and I'm telling the user to color it, I want to know whether he colored just a small part of it or the whole shape.

Comment: @Harsh if I want to do this in background is that possible because TeamViewer does that?